# Multilingual pages and dynamic multilingual content

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am creating a web app that has multilingual pages in dynamic multilingual contents or pages as well. The problem is actually with multilingual contents. When I use visible prop or the repeater component then it works well, but the problem when writes a lot of code,  I think there must be a simpler way for this?

```
<!--Turkish-->
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvListAllProdsTr">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="gallery_box">
                <a rel="lightbox[portfolio]" href='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' title='<%# Eval("ProdNameTr") %>'>
                    <img src='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' />
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">
                        <%# Eval("ProdNameTr") %>
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <a href="#" class="more">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltrDetayTr" Text="Detay" runat="server" /></a>
                <div class="cleaner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:DataPager ID="dpTr" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvListAllProdsTr" PageSize="10">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
<!--Turkish-->

<!--Russian-->
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvListAllProdsRu">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="gallery_box">
                <a rel="lightbox[portfolio]" href='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' title='<%# Eval("ProdNameRu") %>'>
                    <img src='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' />
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">
                        <%# Eval("ProdNameRu") %>
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <a href="#" class="more">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltrDetayTr" Text="Detay" runat="server" /></a>
                <div class="cleaner">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:DataPager ID="dpRu" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvListAllProdsRu" PageSize="10">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
<!--Russian-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of Eval("ProdNameTr") how about calling a method for example :

```
 GetProductName(Container.DataItem)
```

inside this method you read the current locale (if you know by then from the culture or something) and return the appropriate value